# Build asset folder empty : android Studio, using Gradle

Tags: android, fonts, assets, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a simple app in android studio, where I have placed a font under
**src/main/assets/fonts/fontName.ttf**

When running a **build/clean** etc. the asset folder in the build stays empty. `(build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/assets)`

The application runs, no instances of the file are found on the device.

Comment: show your code,atleast the code where you are trying to get the file from assets.

Comment: after a restart of Android studio, the app builds fine. sorry. im sure i tried this before. anyways thanks for you time